# Stein-Shakarchi Real Analysis Ch1 Ex 12a: an open disc in ${\bf R}^2$ is not the disjoint union of open rectangles

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Prove that an open disc in ${\bf R}^2$ is not the disjoint union of open rectangles.
>
> [Hint: What happens to the boundary of any of these rectangles?]

Attempt: Suppose by contradiction that there exists an open disc $O \subset {\bf R}^2$ which is the disjoint union of open rectangles.
Let $R_1 \subset O$ be an open rectangle and let $x \in \partial R_1$ where $\partial R_1$ is the boundary of $R_1$, such that it's the set of points which are in the closure of $R_1$  but not in the interior of $R_1$.

Then by definition of boundary we have that for all $r > 0, B_r(x) \cap R_1 \neq 0$ and $B_r(x) \cap R_1^c \neq 0. $
So $x \notin R_1$...

Comment: One can also argue by connectedness of an open disc. See answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239765/9464

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the idea: if $R_1$ is one of the open rectangles contained in the disk, then we can choose a point $x$ in the disk belonging to the boundary of $R_1$.

Since $R_1$ is open, $x\not\in R_1$, so $x$ must be contained in another one of the rectangles, say $R_2$. And since $R_2$ is open, $x$ must in fact be in the interior of $R_2$. Now all you have to do is show that this implies that $R_1$ and $R_2$ have a non-empty intersection, contrary to the hypothesis.